# A question about the potential energy of ordered marbles in free space

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, potential-energy, information

According to the second law of thermodynamics the entropy of a closed system always increases or stays the same. In case of the presence of potentials the system will evolve to a state with less Gibbs free energy.

Now imagine a huge collection of randomly positioned small massive marbles in a volume of free space, making the entropy of the collection a maximum.

We then arrange the marbles in a pattern. Which means the marbles show a coherent, non-random whole, with less entropy than the random case.

Now at first sight, no potentials seem involved. So it seems the energy of both arrangements is the same. The rest energies of the particles is the same in both cases.

On closer inspection, the marbles are gravitationally interacting, no matter how weak. If in outer space, waiting long enough, they will move towards their center of mass.

My question is, will a random distribution have a lower potential energy than an ordered state?

Answer (score 2):

> Now imagine a huge collection of randomly positioned small massive marbles in a volume of free space, making the entropy of the collection a maximum.

If the configuration is precisely defined, we are dealing with one specific state, having probability $1$, which means that the entropy is zero. In this sense there is no difference between a *random* distribution of marbles and their ordered state.

The entropy becomes a meaningful concept, if we do not know in which exact state the system is - i.e., if many random states are possible. In thermodynamic equilibrium we assume that all the states with the same energy are equally probable.

> On closer inspection, the marbles are gravitationally interacting, no matter how weak. If in outer space, waiting long enough, they will move towards their center of mass.

If the marbles are not able to give away energy, but only exchange energy among themselves, they will not assemble closer to their center-of-mass, but rather continue flying around, colliding. Essentially, we have here a non-ideal gas with hard core repulsive interaction at distances less or equal the radius of a marble, and weak attractive interaction at larges distances.

> My question is, will a random distribution have a lower potential energy than an ordered state?

Assuming that marbles can lose kinetic energy, e.g., it is transferred into their internal energy in collisions or emitted as electromagnetic waves (via some mechanism), then the system will relax to a lower energy state. If this energy state is unique, then we will arrive to it regardless of the initial configuration - provided that we wait long enough. If there are more than one ground state, we will eventually have equal probability of finding a system in any of them. However, the time for equalizing these probabilities may be prohibitively long, in which case one may get an impression that the system is stuck in one or another ground state - we then talk about *phase transitions* (see Anderson's [More is different.](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf) for an excellent discussion).

Comment: If the marbles are stationary in space initially, won't they start moving towards their CoM because of gravity? Isn't there a gravitational potential energy, no matter how small?

Comment: If all marbles on the edge of the volume, then the potential energy is higher then when all near the center.

Comment: @Felicia The marbles will start moving, converting their potential energy into kinetic energy. But they will not stop in the configuration with the lowest *potential energy* but simply continue moving - like a pendulum that does not just stop in its lowest position, but continue swinging... unless it loses energy, e.g., due to friction.

Comment: But suppose they have a fixed position in a volume. How do you know that an ordered configuration has the same gravitational potential energy as a random one.

Comment: @Felicia No, they do not necessarily have the same potential energy. What is essential is that both likely have higher energy than the lowest potential energy. Btw, one could estimate the distribution of energies of random configurations.

Comment: Interesting article! One more question. Wont all marbles settle in the same energetic endstate? And emit different amounts of radiation in the process? Are there different endstates?

Comment: @Felicia If the marbles are distinguishable (classical) then there are multiple endstates - at least as many as there are permutations of the marbles. Then there are also states that differ by rotation, etc. But I don't think that any of the final states are separated by high energy barriers, i.e., I doubt that there are distinct phases (like polarizations of ferromagnet).

Comment: Okay, thanks. Very last question: Does this imply that an ordered (informative?) state has a different weight then a random state of marbles (I ask because I read somewhere that information has mass-energy).

Comment: @Felicia From the information point of view there is nothing special about the ordered state. However, as you noted, the ordered and disordered states do not necessarily have the same energy. So one should distinguish the entropy of the initial distribution of marbles and the thermodynamic entropy (all states with the same energy). Still, if there is no uncertainty about the initial state, the entropy is zero - whether it is ordered or not.

Comment: Can't we say though that the ordered state contains Shannon information or entropy? I mean, if we consider the positions of the marbles zero or one, we could use it as a memory. Say we position them in the volume on a 3D grid. Absence of a marble is 0 and presence a 1.